# must refer to client 'user_1211_hf_pilot1'

Tags: perforce

I want to create a p4 branch based on branch mvs_1211_hf at this label CC2P4_MVS_1211_HF_PILOT1, but the p4 command response is not my expectation. Anyone can help on this? Or is there any ways to create branch in p4? Thanks in advance!

Here is the p4 command i run:
p4 integ //depot/MVS_IMPORT/mvs_1211_hf/tms_dev/...@CC2P4_MVS_1211_HF_PILOT1 //deport/1211_hf/...

Here is the p4 complains:
//deport/1211_hf/... - must refer to client 'ruilong_mvs_1211_hf_pilot1'.

Best regards,
Ruilong

Comment: Is the 'deport' typo in the command or just the post?

Comment: @gaige: The typo must be in the command as that is the exact error such a mistake produces in Perforce.  Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: @gaige, raven thanks for your response, yes the typo cause the error in Perforce.

Answer (score 4):

Typical errors include the ones previously mentioned, plus: 
//depot1/... - must refer to client 'clientname'.

Check the client workspace view by running: 
p4 client -o clientname

Check the "View" lines in the client workspace specification to confirm that the file specification used in your Perforce command (or appearing in the error message) falls within your workspace view.

If needed, change the client workspace by running: 
p4 client clientname

Find more at: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Common-Permissions-and-File-Access-Problems

Thanks

Comment: That link is broken now. I believe this is the new place for that page: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2490

Answer (score 1):

I received this error, when the path simply did not exists... had a typo :/

Answer (score 0):

The `must refer to client <client>` error is the generic error given when an absolute path is neither a valid depot path nor a valid client path within the context of the current client.  In this case, the cause of the error is that you typed `//deport` instead of `//depot`.

It would be more accurate for the error to say `must be a depot path or a client path referring to current client <client>`, but Perforce error messages tend to err on the side of brevity.